# Basic bitmap doesn't show up - GetObject() return null

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to display a bitmap in a window using Visual c++. The bitmap seems to load correctly:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    squareBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, TEXT("C:\\Users\\User1\\ResEdit Projects\\Test1\\bitmap1.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    if (squareBitmap == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(windowHandle, TEXT("Trouble..."), TEXT("Loading square"), MB_OK);
    }
    break;
```

The error message box does not display.

I believe that the problem is in `WM_PAINT` but I don't know what kind of error checking I should do in `WM_PAINT`.

```
BITMAP bm;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(windowHandle, &ps);
    if (hdc == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(windowHandle, TEXT("Trouble..."), TEXT("hdc"), MB_OK);
    }
        HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

    if (hdcMem == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(windowHandle, TEXT("Trouble..."), TEXT("hdcMem"), MB_OK);
    }



    HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, squareBitmap);

    int testGO = GetObject(squareBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
    if (testGO == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(windowHandle, TEXT("Trouble..."), TEXT("hdcObject"), MB_OK);
    }
    //char buffer[20];
    //itoa(bm.bmHeight, buffer, 52);
    //MessageBox(windowHandle, buffer, TEXT(bm.bmHeight), MB_OK);
    int testBB = BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    if (testBB == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(windowHandle, TEXT("Trouble..."), TEXT("testBB"), MB_OK);
    }
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);

    EndPaint(windowHandle, &ps);
    break;
```

`GetObject` is returning NULL. I think this means that I have loaded my resource file incorrectly.

Comment: your code above works for me -- how are you creating your window? is the `WM_PAINT` logic being executed? you could check the values of `hdc`, `hdcMem`, `GetObject()` and `BitBlt()`

Comment: @EdwardClements GetObject() is returning NULL

Comment: Where are your variables (like `squareBitmap`) defined?

Comment: @JonathanPotter They're defined in my handler funciton above the switch statement

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thank you very much -- Took the hint and loaded the image inside the case statement so the image now shows up. If you write it into an answer I would be happy to accept.

Comment: [`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045.aspx): *`hInst`: To load a stand-alone resource [...] set this parameter to `NULL`.* The flag `LR_LOADFROMFILE` instructs the call to load a stand-alone resource. On an unrelated note: Loading the image for each `WM_PAINT` message is needlessly inefficient. Simply mark your `HBITMAP squareBitmap` `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jonathan Potter suggested, I was initializing and loading my image in such a way that they would be `NULL` by the time I got to `WM_PAINT`. So nothing to do with the WinApi, just a logic bug.